Allowing users to organize ContentDocument into folders on a record
I have a Task in Salesforce which people can upload files too. I want to try to allow them to upload them into specific folders. I read about Libraries, but this seems meant for allowing for me as an admin to allow users to pick from a specific stock set of files that I curate for them. I see that there is a ContentWorkspaceDoc that would allow me to link together the Library (ContentWorkspace) to the file (ContentItem). I tried creating a record for this in Workbench, but this seemed to simply share it to that library as a ContentDocumentLink, similar to the way that the act of uploading creates the ContentDocumentLink to the task.
I'm very new to Salesforce so apologies if there's a trailhead that I should reference for this or a different object I'm missing. I wasn't able to find any settings to allow folders for files. Thanks for any guidance you can share.
